# BITCOIN GOLD CLAIMING FROM BITCOIN STORED IN LEDGER HW1

Tags: bitcoin-gold

prefork time of BTG ,i stored my bitcoins in LEDGER HW1 HARDWARE WALLET,STORED IN SEGWIT address.Coinomy NOT supporting segwit address stored bitcoins it only supporting legacy address stored bitcoins to claim BTG.My question is how can i claim BTG from segwit address stored bitcoin in LEDGER HW1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the Ledger BTG app? It should give you access to your BTG forked coins if they are attached to the same private key as your per-fork BTC coins.